# Reading a variable from a file and sending that to a command

Tags: bash, archlinux

I'm trying to automate a build process that requires retrieving a list of dependencies from a file and then piping those into a command. I have a loop to auto download the packages I am building, but I need to then read a file and get a list of dependencies. What I'm trying to do is this:

```
cd ${pkg}
then read this line from a file called PKGBUILD: depends=('dep1' 'dep2')
paru -S dep1 dep2
```

Is there any way to do this? I'm new to bash but I have (copied) this code already:
The problem with this code is it doesn't retrieve some dependencies as they are in the AUR so makepkg doesn't auto retrieve them.

```
build_pkgs () {
    { echo; echo "Building AUR Packages - "; echo; }
    cd $DIR/aur_pkgs
    for pkg in "${PKGS[@]}"; do
        echo "Building ${pkg}..."
        cd ${pkg} && makepkg -s
        mv *.pkg.tar.zst $DIR/x86_64
        # Verify
        while true; do
            set -- $DIR/x86_64/$pkg-*
            if [[ -f "$1" ]]; then
                { echo; echo "Package '${pkg}' generated successfully."; echo; }
                break
            else
                { echo; echo "Failed to build '${pkg}', Exiting..." >&2; }
                { echo; exit 1; }
            fi
        done
        cd $DIR/aur_pkgs
    done    
}
```

Comment: Use `yay` or other manager that does just that for you.

Comment: I would, however, my goal is to try and build large packages to use on low powered devices such as my laptop. As I compile a modified kernel among other large packages, it isn't viable to do on every device.

Comment: No. I meant use an AUR helper _to build the packages_ and collect builded packages, not to install them on target machine. Then copy the result with the dependencies from yay cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> read this line from a file called PKGBUILD: depends=('dep1' 'dep2')
> ```

Archlinux PKGBUILDs are written in bash by themselves - just source it and output.

```
. PKGBUILD
echo "${depends[@]}"
```

You would preferably do it "safely" in a subshell and transfer the value of the variable with `declare -p` so that not to modify parent environment.

But `makepkg` itself is written in bash, so just [see it's sources how it's doing](https://git.archlinux.org/pacman.git/tree/scripts/makepkg.sh.in#n1209) [and here](https://git.archlinux.org/pacman.git/tree/scripts/libmakepkg/util/util.sh.in#n104).

Anyway, so many archlinux users write their own small set of scripts to setup their own repository - [there are so many of them](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/unofficial_user_repositories) and all of them needed to solve that problem. Instead of reinventing the wheel and fixing same mistakes as others did, consider rather searching for a ready-to-use solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I knew that PKGBUILDS were written in bash, I'm just quite new so I didn't think of sourcing it and using a variable to install the dependencies. I know there are a lot of user repo's, and I would normally just use an AUR helper,  however, a lot of these packages are either custom, modified in some way, or too large to compile every update on my devices, so I've been using a github action to compile everything. Nonetheless, I thank you for your help.

Comment: You missed the point. The point is _not_ to use AUR helpers and _not_ to use other repositories. The point is _each_ of these repositories use a similar script and similar automated ci/cd to build. Instead of writing your own solution, research how they do it and use the same.

Comment: Ah, I see. I misread what you said. I'll go and look at those, thanks!

Comment: Turns out that Paru, which I was using to install the dependencies of various packages supports just passing the packages to it and it'll output the files. This was a lot of work for nothing lol. Thanks for your help!